# C# Use SourceGenerator with CSharpCompilation

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

**Leading Question**

Is it possible to use `ISourceGenerator` with `CSharpCompilation.Create(...)`?

**Background**

I've created a Roslyn SourceGenerator based on `ISourceGenerator`. This generator creates some partial classes with code that I don't want to write myself and can be generated from attributes and stuff. It works well in VisualStudio.

I've also created another programm that generates C# code and uses `CSharpCompilation.Create(...)` to compile it in memory.

Now I want to combine the two, so the later programm can skip the parts that the SourceGenerator will generate while compiling the code.

I know SourceGenerators are not stable, so is this use case already implemented?

I tryed to use `MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MyGenerator).Assembly.Location)` and feed it to `CSharpCompilation.Create(references: x)` but it didn't work =/

I know for Analyzers there is an extension method `WithAnalyzers`, but Analyzers work differently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a GeneratorDriver API that you can use. As a caveat, as of this writing the API is still considered beta and could change, but I suspect as long as you stick to the process below it should be good.

Basically how the API is works is you:

1. Call `CSharpGeneratorDriver.Create`, passing in the list of generators.
2. Call [this method](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/a4cae91ca9dc0e33b628b91b0a9a88334e6edc6c/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/SourceGeneration/GeneratorDriver.cs#L54) which you pass in your compilation, and it gives you a new compilation with the generated trees added.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. One important detail is that the SyntaxTree needs to be parsed with the latest version of C# to support SourceGenerators, but the thrown Exception is straight forward.